# Remote connection to iseries

Tags: database-connection, ibm-midrange

I'm a php developer trying to learn about the IBM i.

Is there a way to connect to the IBM i to list/view objects/members without using an odbc connection/sql?

I've considered using ftp, but seems too hacky for what I'm doing.

Any input is helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-connect.php

Comment: iSeries is the name of a much earlier model of the IBM midrange computing platform.  You may be able to find 2016 information by looking for 'iSeries' or 'AS/400' but you'd be more likely to find outdated information with those search terms.  Searching for 'IBM i' will return more up to date information.  Start at the IBM Knowledge Center link in Charles' answer.

Comment: Don't be Sorry, Be Safe.

Answer (score 3):

[Paul Bastide's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335510/remote-connection-to-iseries/37341480#comment62190126_37335510) is correct with using http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-connect.php. By combining it with the [system catalogs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/db2/rbafzmstcatalogtbls.htm%23catalogtbls) you can get any file/table and member related information. For example to get all the source members in a source file:

```
SELECT sys_mname
FROM syspartitionstat
WHERE sys_tname = 'QRPGLESRC'
  AND sys_dname = 'SOURCELIB'
```

For none database related objects you will have to wrap a [system API](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/apifinder/finder.htm) in a SQL Stored Procedure or get an AS400 developer to write you a SOAP/REST service to get the information you need.

Answer (score 2):

> without ODBC connection/sql

Says to me you're looking for a "native" interface to the OS & DB.

In that case, you have two choices

1. 5250 "green screen" terminal emulator.  IBM and others have commercial ones, or there's some open source TN5250 packages.
2. GUI interface, "Navigator for i"

Option 2 is available in two flavors:

1. stabilized fat client "System i Navigator" component of IBM i Access for Windows.
2. server based "IBM Navigator for i" web interface (http://systemName:2001)

Take a look at the [Connecting to your system](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahg/rzahgicinterface.htm)  section of the IBM Infocenter.

Answer (score 0):

No mention of what FTP would do for you, but per *list/view objects/members*, I suppose the implication is the ability to perform a dir or ls?  If so, then just map a network drive, and use whatever is a preferred directory navigation tool.